I2C register reading with long wait time
I'm developing a vibration and temperature analysis system.
To do this, I have developed a sensor based on an STM32L053C8 chip and a KX122-1037 accelerometer.
Looking at the datasheet, this accelerometer can reach a maximum data rate of 25600Hz, which is great for my analysis since I need to generate an FFT of the received data.
My operation is as follows: I have a number of vibration samples that I need to collect, currently I'm using 2048 samples. These samples need to be collected over 1 second, so that they represent one of the operating frequencies of the machine being analyzed. In other words, I need to take 2048 accelerometer vibration readings in 1 second equally spaced by a microsecond delay.
My problem lies in this part of the reading. The time between readings is too long, so I've connected a led that stays on after the reading is taken and goes off when a new reading starts. This way I could measure the waiting time, and I arrived at 4 seconds for the 2048 data to be read.
This shouldn't be happening, right? The speed of my I2C is Fast Plus at 1000KHz. According to the data sheet, reading data from an accelerometer register is also very fast.
So why is it taking so long?
How can I fix it?
main.c file setup:
#define ACC_DATA_RATE 25800

#define KX122_DEVICE_ADDRESS_1E   (0x1E)    // 7bit Address
#define KX122_DEVICE_ADDRESS_1F   (0x1F)    // 7bit Address
#define KX122_WAI_VAL             (0x1B)

#define KX122_XOUT_L              (0x06)
#define KX122_WHO_AM_I            (0x0F)
#define KX122_CNTL1               (0x18)
#define KX122_ODCNTL              (0x1B)

#define KX122_CNTL1_TPE           (1 << 0)
#define KX122_CNTL1_WUFE          (1 << 1)
#define KX122_CNTL1_TDTE          (1 << 2)
#define KX122_CNTL1_GSELMASK      (0x18)
#define KX122_CNTL1_GSEL_2G       (0x00)
#define KX122_CNTL1_GSEL_4G       (0x08)
#define KX122_CNTL1_GSEL_8G       (0x10)
#define KX122_CNTL1_DRDYE         (1 << 5)
#define KX122_CNTL1_RES           (1 << 6)
#define KX122_CNTL1_PC1           (1 << 7)

#define KX122_ODCNTL_OSA_50HZ     (2)
#define KX122_ODCNTL_LPRO         (1 << 6)
#define KX122_IIR_BYPASS          (1 << 7)

#define KX122_CNTL1_VAL           (KX122_CNTL1_RES | KX122_CNTL1_GSEL_2G)
#define KX122_ODCNTL_VAL          (0x0F)

#define BUF_CNTL1 0x3A
#define BUF_CNTL2 0x3B
#define BUF_STATUS_1 0x3C
#define BUF_STATUS_2 0x3D
#define BUF_CLEAR 0x3E
#define BUF_READ 0x3F

unsigned short _g_sens;

typedef struct {
  float x;
  float y;
  float z;
} Vibration;
static void MX_I2C1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 1 */
  hi2c1.Instance = I2C1;
  hi2c1.Init.Timing = 0x00000000;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress1 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.AddressingMode = I2C_ADDRESSINGMODE_7BIT;
  hi2c1.Init.DualAddressMode = I2C_DUALADDRESS_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2 = 0;
  hi2c1.Init.OwnAddress2Masks = I2C_OA2_NOMASK;
  hi2c1.Init.GeneralCallMode = I2C_GENERALCALL_DISABLE;
  hi2c1.Init.NoStretchMode = I2C_NOSTRETCH_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_I2C_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Analogue filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigAnalogFilter(&hi2c1, I2C_ANALOGFILTER_ENABLE) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** Configure Digital filter
  */
  if (HAL_I2CEx_ConfigDigitalFilter(&hi2c1, 0) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  /** I2C Fast mode Plus enable
  */
  HAL_I2CEx_EnableFastModePlus(I2C_FASTMODEPLUS_I2C1);
  /* USER CODE BEGIN I2C1_Init 2 */

  /* USER CODE END I2C1_Init 2 */

}

Write and Read Registers: Writing to a Register:
static HAL_StatusTypeDef KX122_WriteRegister(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint8_t reg, uint8_t value) {
    uint8_t data[2] = { reg, value };
    return HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(hi2c, KX122_DEVICE_ADDRESS_1F << 1, data, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

Reading from a Register:
HAL_StatusTypeDef KX122_ReadRegisters(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *data, uint16_t length) {
    return HAL_I2C_Mem_Read(hi2c, KX122_DEVICE_ADDRESS_1F << 1, reg, I2C_MEMADD_SIZE_8BIT, data, length, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}
static HAL_StatusTypeDef KX122_WriteRegister(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint8_t reg, uint8_t value) {
    uint8_t data[2] = { reg, value };
    return HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(hi2c, KX122_DEVICE_ADDRESS_1F << 1, data, 2, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}

static HAL_StatusTypeDef KX122_ReadRegister(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, uint8_t reg, uint8_t *data) {
    HAL_StatusTypeDef status;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        status = HAL_I2C_Master_Transmit(hi2c, KX122_DEVICE_ADDRESS_1F << 1, &reg, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
        if (status == HAL_OK) {
            status = HAL_I2C_Master_Receive(hi2c, KX122_DEVICE_ADDRESS_1F << 1, data, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
            if (status == HAL_OK) {
                return HAL_OK;
            }
        }
    }
    return status;
}

Initialization of KX122: KX122 Initialization Function:
HAL_StatusTypeDef KX122_Init(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c) {
      HAL_StatusTypeDef rc;
      unsigned char reg;
      unsigned char gsel;
      int i;

      rc = KX122_ReadRegister(hi2c, KX122_WHO_AM_I, &reg);
      if (rc != HAL_OK) {
        DEBUG_PRINT("Can't access KX122 \r\n");
        return (rc);
      }

      DEBUG_PRINT("KX122_WHO_AMI Register Value = 0x \r\n");
      DEBUG_PRINT_REGISTER(KX122_WHO_AM_I, reg);

      if (reg != KX122_WAI_VAL) {
          DEBUG_PRINT("Can't find KX122 \r\n");
        return HAL_ERROR;
      }

      reg = KX122_CNTL1_VAL;
      rc = KX122_WriteRegister(hi2c, KX122_CNTL1, KX122_CNTL1_VAL);
      if (rc != HAL_OK) {
          DEBUG_PRINT("Can't write KX122 CNTL1 register at first \r\n");
        return (rc);
      }

      reg = KX122_ODCNTL_VAL;
      rc = KX122_WriteRegister(hi2c, KX122_ODCNTL, KX122_ODCNTL_VAL);
      if (rc != HAL_OK) {
          DEBUG_PRINT("Can't write KX122 ODCNTL register \r\n");
        return (rc);
      }

      rc = KX122_ReadRegister(hi2c, KX122_CNTL1, &reg);
      if (rc != HAL_OK) {
          DEBUG_PRINT("Can't read KX122 CNTL1 register \r\n");
        return (rc);
      }
      gsel = reg & KX122_CNTL1_GSELMASK;

      reg |= KX122_CNTL1_PC1;
      rc = KX122_WriteRegister(hi2c, KX122_CNTL1, reg);
      if (rc != HAL_OK) {
          DEBUG_PRINT("Can't write KX122 CNTL1 register at second \r\n");
        return (rc);
      }

      switch(gsel) {
        case KX122_CNTL1_GSEL_2G : _g_sens = 16384; break;
        case KX122_CNTL1_GSEL_4G : _g_sens = 8192;  break;
        case KX122_CNTL1_GSEL_8G : _g_sens = 4096;  break;
        default: break;
      }

    return HAL_OK;
}

HAL_StatusTypeDef KX122_StartBuffer(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c){
      HAL_StatusTypeDef rc;
      int8_t cntlreg;
      int8_t reg;

      rc = KX122_ReadRegister(hi2c, KX122_CNTL1, &cntlreg);
      if (rc != HAL_OK) {
          DEBUG_PRINT("Can't read KX122 CNTL1 register \r\n");
        return (rc);
      }

      DEBUG_PRINT_REGISTER(KX122_CNTL1, cntlreg);

      reg = 0x00;
      rc = KX122_WriteRegister(hi2c, KX122_CNTL1, reg);
      if (rc != HAL_OK) {
          DEBUG_PRINT("Can't write KX122 CNTL1 register \r\n");
        return (rc);
      }

      if (KX122_WriteRegister(hi2c, BUF_CNTL2, 0xC0) != HAL_OK) return HAL_ERROR; // 16 bits FILO
      if (KX122_WriteRegister(hi2c, BUF_CLEAR, 0x80) != HAL_OK) return HAL_ERROR; // Clear buffer

      //rc = KX122_WriteRegister(&hi2c1, BUF_CNTL1, 681);  // Set watermark level to 681 samples (3 axes per sample)

      rc = KX122_WriteRegister(hi2c, KX122_CNTL1, cntlreg);
      if (rc != HAL_OK) {
          DEBUG_PRINT("Can't write KX122 CNTL1 register \r\n");
        return (rc);
      }

      DEBUG_PRINT("Start buffer! \r\n");
      return HAL_OK;
}

Reading Accelerometer Data Function:
HAL_StatusTypeDef KX122_ReadAccelData(I2C_HandleTypeDef *hi2c, float *data, Vibration *vib) {
    HAL_StatusTypeDef rc;
    int8_t val[6];
    signed short acc[3];
    rc =  KX122_ReadRegisters(hi2c, KX122_XOUT_L, &val, sizeof(val));
    if (rc != HAL_OK) {
        DEBUG_PRINT("Can't get KX122 accel value \r\n");
    }
    acc[0] = ((int16_t)val[1] << 8) | (val[0]);
    acc[1] = ((int16_t)val[3] << 8) | (val[2]);
    acc[2] = ((int16_t)val[5] << 8) | (val[4]);
    data[0] = (float)acc[0] / _g_sens;
    data[1] = (float)acc[1] / _g_sens;
    data[2] = (float)acc[2] / _g_sens;
    vib->x = data[0];
    vib->y = data[1];
    vib->z = data[2];
    return (rc);
}

Main Function: System Setup:
int main(void) {
    HAL_Init();
    SystemClock_Config();
    MX_GPIO_Init();
    MX_USART1_UART_Init();
    MX_I2C1_Init();
    MX_SPI1_Init();
    TIM2_Init();
    setup();
    while (1) {
        loop();
    }
}

Setup and Loop Functions: Setup Function:
void setup() {
    DEBUG_PRINT("Setup...\r\n");
    I2C_Scan();
    if (KX122_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_ERROR)
        DEBUG_PRINT("KX122 Ready\r\n");
    if (FRAM_Init(&hi2c1) != HAL_ERROR)
        DEBUG_PRINT("FRAM Ready\r\n");
    writeVibrationInformation();
}

Loop Function:
void loop() {
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    DEBUG_PRINT("read...\r\n");
    HAL_Delay(1000);
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    writeVibrationInformation();
}
void writeVibrationInformation() {
    float accel[3];
    data.rms_accel[0] = 0.0;
    data.rms_accel[1] = 0.0;
    data.rms_accel[2] = 0.0;

    data.rms_vel[0] = 0.0;
    data.rms_vel[1] = 0.0;
    data.rms_vel[2] = 0.0;

    float velocity_x = 0.0;
    float velocity_y = 0.0;
    float velocity_z = 0.0;
    
    Vibration vibration;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2048 ; i++) {
        KX122_ReadAccelData(&hi2c1, accel, &vibration); //Here I take the axis readings

        data.rms_accel[0] += (vibration.x * vibration.x);
        data.rms_accel[1] += (vibration.y * vibration.y);
        data.rms_accel[2] += (vibration.z * vibration.z);

        float deltaTime = sampling_period_us / 1e6;

        data.rms_vel[0] += (vibration.x * vibration.x) * deltaTime; //Ax * dT
        data.rms_accel[1] += (vibration.y * vibration.y) * deltaTime; //Ay * dT
        data.rms_vel[2] += (vibration.z * vibration.z) * deltaTime; //Az * dT

        address += sizeof(float);

        //delayMicroseconds(sampling_period_us);
    }

    data.rms_accel[0] = sqrt(data.rms_accel[0] / SAMPLES);
    data.rms_accel[1] = sqrt(data.rms_accel[1] / SAMPLES);
    data.rms_accel[2] = sqrt(data.rms_accel[2] / SAMPLES);

    char buffer[256];
    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer),
            "RMS Accel: %.2f, %.2f, %.2f\r\nRMS Vel: %.4f, %.4f, %.4f\r\n",
            data.rms_accel[0], data.rms_accel[1], data.rms_accel[2],
            data.rms_vel[0], data.rms_vel[1], data.rms_vel[2]);
    DEBUG_PRINT(buffer);
}

Previously I used an atmega chip with an ADXL345, it worked well, but its ODR only goes up to 1600Hz, I need to develop new devices that go up to 25KHz, that's why I chose the k122.


You should only read the samples under an interrupt filling a buffer ... then do other tasks.

Interesting! Could you tell me how I could do that?

Don't know very well STM32L053C8 chip and KX122-1037. I think that interrupt should be used for the fastest part (sampling data) of the program, with the use of the DMA scheme. But, sorry, I can't help you ... I never used this processor.

Okay! I'll study up on it.
One doubt, according to the datasheet the SPI connection is 3 times faster than I2C, do you think I should start using SPI?

Seems that SPI (10 or 16 Mbits/s) is 10x faster than I2C (1 Mbits/s), so yes. Start with SPI.

See this p264  https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/rm0367-ultralowpower-stm32l0x3-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf

And this, page 987 :  §A.8.9 DMA one shot mode sequence code example

You use a lot of floating point operations in the sampling loop, some of them even twice (vibration * vibration) and calculate the same deltaTime 2048 times. Can you run the loop with all the float calculations and the divisions in KX122_ReadAccelData disabled for comparision? This is a 32 MHz integer CPU without FPU, would be interesting what the math costs here. The value data.rms_vel[1] is nowhere calculated, bug?.

I've developed a new board with SPI, I'll bring you updates soon.

Okay, even with SPI it took more than a second, I removed the mathematical operations and it was faster, but still more than a second. What are my options? I thought of making an algorithm to read 128 samples 8 times, which would result in 1024 total samples.
